# Slackware 14: make install

Tags: makefile, slackware, linux

Мне понадобилось создать .txz вручную, без файла .Slackbuild. Нашёл кучу мануалов для стареньких версии, в которых предлогалось сделать так:

```
make install DESTDIR=/tmp/files
```

И уже внутри этой директории выполнять команду makepkg для создания пакета.

Но данная команда не помогла. Собраные файлы всё равно копировались прямиком в рабочие каталоги. Есть у кого опыт? Может быть можно сделать .txz другим путём?

Comment: Приведи полный перечень команд которые запускал, начиная с ./configure

Comment: собственно ./configure ,затем make -j4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну, судя по всему не указал **куда** это все складывать:

```
  $ cd /tmp/files  $ makepkg -l y -c n ../pkg.tgz
```

Answer (score 0):

loadlin zimage rw, root=/dev/ram initrd=color.gz load_ramdisk=1 -------- есле флопи диск